# how to arrange layout for questions like( fill in the blanks ) in adapter android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am inflating **TExtView**,**edittext** and **TExtView** to the adapter for listView for different questions like below:

**what is your name ______.
tajmahal is in _______ country.
________  is a apple.**

```xml
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newtextview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/blank_set"
            android:ems="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/textQuestiontwo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

But I **do not** want the item in **listview to scroll horizontally**. Of course if I make comment the horizontall scrollview textviews are ommiting some characters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found any solution??

Answer (score 1):

It is not simple,

You have to arrange particular number of controls (EditText, Button etc.) in particular layout horizontally and then below add same layout with having your controls and so on...

**1.** You need to use multiple LinearLayout with horizontal orientation

**2.** Add required items into them as per your sequence (You can manage the items width by weight)

Make sure you are covering your desired screen resolutions.

*Although you can have same implementation in dynamic manner but it is very time consuming, you  need to calculate the device available width and then dynamically add your required items into layouts but it is not recommended.*

Comment: is there any alternative to this

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented similar feature for my need. Copy below two files into your project.

**FillObject.java**

```
public class FillObject {

public String text;
public Boolean isTextView;
public int lineNumber;

public FillObject(String text, Boolean isTextView, int lineNumber) {
    this.text = text;
    this.isTextView = isTextView;
    this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Boolean getTextView() {
    return isTextView;
}

public void setTextView(Boolean textView) {
    isTextView = textView;
}

public int getLineNumber() {
    return lineNumber;
}

public void setLineNumber(int lineNumber) {
    this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
}
}
```

**FillInTheBlank.java**

```
public class FillInTheBlank {


public static ArrayList<EditText> createFillInTheBlanks(Context context, LinearLayout linearl, ArrayList<FillObject> map) {

    ArrayList<EditText> editTextArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int lineNumber = 0;
    LinearLayout linearLayout = null;
    for (FillObject fillObject : map) {

        if (fillObject.getLineNumber() != lineNumber) {
            lineNumber = fillObject.getLineNumber();
            linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearl.addView(linearLayout);
        }
        if (fillObject.getTextView()) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setText(fillObject.getText());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 16);
            textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            textView.setTextSize(20f);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);

        } else {
            EditText editText = new EditText(context);
            editText.setHint(fillObject.getText());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams1.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 16);
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
            editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            editTextArrayList.add(editText);
        }
    }
    return editTextArrayList;
}

}
```

**HOW TO USE:**

```
        // param1 = "string"
        // param2 = true(textview), false(edittext)
        // param3 = line number(1,2,3)

        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject("what is your name ", true, 1));
        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject("<name here?", false, 1));
        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject(".tajmahal is in ", true, 2));
        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject("<country here>", false, 2));
        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject(".country", true, 3));
        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject("<something>", false, 3));
        fillInTheBlanks.add(new FillObject("is an apple", true, 3));
        //rootLinearLayout is a LinearLayout with vertical orienation
       ArrayList<EditText> editTextArrayList = FillInTheBlank.createFillInTheBlanks(getContext(), rootLinearLayout, fillInTheBlanks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use WebView and `<input>` tag to display blank element in your context. You can use `css` to decorate your blank format and javascript to obtain the value from `<input>` tag.